# How can I create a TextBox that contains three other TextBoxes to collect date, month and year from the user respectively in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I am new to WPF and Control Templating.

I have a MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox which displays a "Date of Birth" hint to my users when it is empty.

[image: Like this]

Here is what I want to implement: the TextBox to display three TextBoxes to the user when clicked in like this, so that my users enter the date part they know:

[image: Like this]

This is because my Users sometimes only know some parts of the date such as Year and Month Only, That was why i didn't use the DatePicker.
The other thing that became hard to implement was the TextBox to display to the Use the date as following When it has a value:

[image: Full Date]

[image: Month and Year]

[image: Year Only]

Here is what I tried.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DateTextBoxApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DateTextBoxApp"
        xmlns:materialdesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Dark.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.Green.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <Style x:Key="NameTextBox" TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}">
                <Setter Property="materialdesign:HintAssist.HintOpacity" Value="0.35"/>
                <Setter Property="materialdesign:ColorZoneAssist.Mode" Value="Dark"/>
                <Setter Property="materialdesign:HintAssist.HintOpacity" Value="0.35"/>
                <Setter Property="materialdesign:HintAssist.FontFamily" Value="Century Gothic"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="AliceBlue"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="DateTextBox" TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}">
                <Setter Property="materialdesign:HintAssist.HintOpacity" Value="0.35"/>
                <Setter Property="materialdesign:ColorZoneAssist.Mode" Value="Dark"/>
                <Setter Property="materialdesign:HintAssist.HintOpacity" Value="0.35"/>
                <Setter Property="materialdesign:HintAssist.FontFamily" Value="Century Gothic"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="AliceBlue"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <TextBox x:Name="DayTextBox" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='dd'}" TextAlignment="Center" Width="80"
                                                 materialdesign:HintAssist.Hint="Day" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}"/>
                                        <TextBox x:Name="MonthTextBox"  Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='MM'}" TextAlignment="Center" Width="80"
                                                 materialdesign:HintAssist.Hint="Month" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}"/>
                                        <TextBox x:Name="YearTextBox"  Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='yyyy'}" TextAlignment="Center"  Width="160"
                                                 materialdesign:HintAssist.Hint="Year" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                        <!-- Set the keyboard focus to the DayTextBox -->
                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=DayTextBox}" />
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF06013F" Offset="1"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF040F2E"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
        <StackPanel Margin="30" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="80">
            <TextBox Style="{StaticResource NameTextBox}" Width="100" materialdesign:HintAssist.Hint="FirstName" Margin="0 0 50 0"/>
            <TextBox Style="{StaticResource DateTextBox}" Text="{Binding DOB}" Width="200" materialdesign:HintAssist.Hint="Date Of Birth"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But the problem is that the Textboxes don't accept Inputs, Why? and How can I achieve this?

[image: Here is an animation of the error]

Comment: Oh I forget to add that i store everything as a Text even in SQL Server (Nvarchar)

Comment: You should have 3 textboxes  bound to 3 viewmodel properties for your partial date entry. You could have them enter slashes r something between the parts of a date and split the string, but I think that'd be worse.

Answer (score 1):

What type of Date property is in your ViewModel? I suspect it's DateTime. It will not be possible to enter it in parts. Try this simple example to understand it:

```cs
    public class DateMaimViewModel
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

```xml
    <StackPanel>
        <FrameworkElement.DataContext>
            <local:DateMaimViewModel/>
        </FrameworkElement.DataContext>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='MM'}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Try using your custom type with an implementation like this:

```cs
    public class OnlyDate : ViewModelBase
    {
        public int? Year { get => Get<int>(); set => Set(value); }
        public int? Mount { get => Get<int>(); set => Set(value); }
        public int? Day { get => Get<int>(); set => Set(value); }

        public bool IsCorrect { get => Get<bool>(); private set => Set(value); }

        protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName, object? oldValue, object? newValue)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName, oldValue, newValue);

            int year = Year ?? 1;
            int month = Mount ?? 1;
            int day = Day ?? 1;

            try
            {
                DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, day);
                IsCorrect = true;
            }
            catch
            {
                IsCorrect = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

You asked in the comments how to create the viewModel. Here is a more complete example:

```cs
    public class DateMaimViewModel
    {
        public OnlyDate Date { get;} = new OnlyDate();
    }

    public class OnlyDate : ViewModelBase
    {
        public int? Year { get => Get<int?>(); set => Set(value); }
        public int? Mount { get => Get<int?>(); set => Set(value); }
        public int? Day { get => Get<int?>(); set => Set(value); }

        public bool NotCorrect { get => Get<bool>(); private set => Set(value); }

        public DateTime Date { get => Get<DateTime>(); private set => Set(value.Date); }

        protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName, object? oldValue, object? newValue)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName, oldValue, newValue);

            if (propertyName is nameof(Year) or nameof(Mount) or nameof(Day))
            {
                int year = Year ?? 1;
                int month = Mount ?? 1;
                int day = Day ?? 1;

                try
                {
                    DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, day);
                    NotCorrect = false;
                    Date = date;
                }
                catch
                {
                    NotCorrect = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```xml
    <StackPanel>
        <FrameworkElement.DataContext>
            <local:DateMaimViewModel/>
        </FrameworkElement.DataContext>
        <Border Margin="5" BorderThickness="2"
                DataContext="{Binding Date}">
            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NotCorrect}"
                                        Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox Margin="5" MinWidth="30" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                            Text="{Binding Day}"/>
                <TextBox Margin="5" MinWidth="30" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                            Text="{Binding Mount}"/>
                <TextBox Margin="5" MinWidth="30" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                            Text="{Binding Year}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
        <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding Date.Date}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

**P.S.** The implementation details depend on what base class you use for the ViewModel and the GUI styling you want.

**P.S.S.** If you use the "Community Toolkit" then it has [TextBoxExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/extensions/textboxextensions), with which you can also customize the TextBox.

Comment: Hi @EldHasp , Thanks for the reply. Can you please help me in creating the viewModel, I am new to WPF and i know little about MVVM Pattern. Where can i put the first class you gave and last class? For the XAML i know i will put it in my MainWindow

Comment: Hi @EldHasp , I am storing it as a String not as DateTime

Comment: @Moha, I've added a more complete example to my answer.

Comment: If you use a string, then this especially does not allow you to edit it in parts. In Sharpe, strings are immutable objects.

Comment: Hi @EldHasp, leave about datetime. How can i Create a Control Like this One?

Comment: Hi @Moha! Add properties for time. You can use TimeSpan or just int for hours and minutes. Checking for correctness is similar to checking the date.